# Format file output like excel?

Tags: unix

I want to format the following output like excel format in linux.

```
ersPea Inc.
www.sdfikpea.com/
0
5

werd inc
www.werds.com
34242
5
```

To

```
ersPea Inc. www.sdfikpea.com/ 0 5

werd inc www.werds.com 34242 5
```

Comment: I see no differnces... You maybe want to generate a CSV file. This can be opened with excel.

Comment: what is the difference between "from" and "to" exactly?

Comment: SO formatting problems, but I'm not going to edit a question that's going to be closed in five minutes.

Comment: @Juhana comon so much work was that not ;)

Answer (score 1):

```sh
sed 'N;N;N;y/\n/ /;N'
```

- read in 3 extra lines
- replace newlines with spaces
- read in empty line

Answer (score 0):

```
 sed '5~5b;N;N;N;y/\n/\s/' inputfile
```